# Design a Turing Machine for binary addition

Tags: turing-machines

I have been working on the following problem:

> Let $\newcommand{\bin}{\operatorname{bin}}\bin\colon \{0,1\}^* \to \mathbb{N}$ convert a binary representation of a non-negative integer to that integer, with the last symbol of the input being the LSB. For example, $\bin(110) = \bin(00110) = 6$ and $\bin() = 0$.
>
> Design a Turing machine that decides the following language: $$\{x\#y\#z : x,y,z \in \{0,1\}^* 
> \text{ and } \bin(x) + \bin(y) = \bin(z) \}. $$

For solving binary addition, full adder seems to be a way to go. I was able to construct a half adder, now things are getting complex and I seem to be stuck, I need a way through which I can send a carry value back to a new half adder or something like that.

I have been using following sample input $1000\#0101\#1101$, which should be accepted since $8+5=13$.

Below is the state diagram I have constructed:

[image: Image of my current Turing machine]

Sample Inputs and Expected Outputs
[image]

Comment: `I need a way through which I can send a carry value back to [more state changes]` The way to keep information about former machine operation used to be called *state*. Once "computing in one direction" works, you can decide about the other direction (x = z-y).

Comment: Oh, wait, if not planning on "bidirectional computation", how about overwriting $z$'s least significant digit with one of { blank, # } depending on carry/"borrow"?